# How do I connect the value of a select menu to an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I've made a dropdown menu using an API.  The menu contains the values of this link. Now I want to get the value you click on from the dropdownmenu in a different API link.

How do I get the value from the menu as a text inside my other link?

```js
var $select = $("#getlist")

function getbreedlist(data) {
  $select.html("#getlist");
  for (var breed in data.message) {
    // console.log(breed);
    $select.append("<option>" + breed + "</option>");
  }
};

function getpictures(breed) {
  for (var name in data.message)
    var url = `https://dog.ceo/api/breed?name=${name}/images`;

  $.ajax({
    url = url,
    dataType: 'json',
    succes: showpictures,
  });

  function showpictures() {
    console.log('pictures are shown')
```

Comment: Hook a `change` event handler to the `select` element, then read the value from it before making whatever call you need. The latter code to make the request you already have.

Comment: Could you write a little example maybe? I'm very new to coding and I don't precisely get what you're telling me...

Answer (score 0):

Have to configure onChange.

Look at this example:

In html:

```
<select id="mySelect" onChange="getStuff()">
    <option >dog1</option>
    <option >dog2</option>
    <option >dog3</option>
</select>
```

In JavaScript:

```
function getStuff(){

    var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    //Here you call your ajax using sel.value
    console.log(sel.value)
}
```